# How generate url in angular ui-router and put it to location

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

View has controls for selecting cities and selecting params. And this view show selected objects for the selected cities. When view is loaded I parse the url and do request to the server. Url for the view are some as: http://example.com/cities?cityId=3&cityId=33&param1=value1. My questions:

1. how can I put that url in location?
2. how can I handle changed url in location?
3. in which event I must hang the handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Url generating automatically by $state.go('cities', {/* params */}, {location: true}).

In controller I put handler in $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess'..

Answer (score 2):

You can generate URL with

```
$location.url('cities?cityId=3&param1=value1');
```

and You can handle this in your router config `$stateProvider` where you define states

```
.state('cities', {
          url: "/cities?cityId&param1",
          templateUrl: "....",
          controller: "citiesController"
        })
// will match to url of "/cities?cityId=[any id]&param1=[any value]"
```

and finally You can have these parameters in the **citiesController.js** i.e

```
console.log($stateParams);
//Object {cityId: "3", param1: "value1"}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In which event I must hang handler?

Comment: @DenniAdam Check the edited version of my answer I've explained there the state defination for your `$stateProvider` config.

Comment: Thanks, you are helped me!

Comment: @DenniAdam Great. If my answer helped you with your problem, You should mark it correct. Glad I can help.